# Any li should be deleted upon clicking 'x', but only last li can be deleted

Tags: jquery, ajax

**Javascript**

```
$('.btn-delete').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $galleryItem = $(this).closest('.prj-item');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/deletePart/' + $(this).data('id'),
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (response) {

                $galleryItem.fadeOut(500, function () {
                    $galleryItem.remove();
                })

            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);

            }
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<li class="prj-item">
    <div class="pure-u-1-4">
        <div class="prj-image filled" style="background-image:url('/image/1.jpg')">
        </div>
        <a data-id="${part.id}" class="btn-delete-part" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="icn-close-white"></i></a>
    </div>
</li>

<li class="prj-item">
    <div class="pure-u-1-4">
        <div class="prj-image filled" style="background-image:url('/image/2.jpg')">
        </div>
        <a data-id="${part.id}" class="btn-delete-part" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="icn-close-white"></i></a>
    </div>
</li>
```

There would be a list of images in each li with description and 'x' icon for delete. When trying to click on 'x' of the first li, it wouldn't be removed. Only the last li could be removed, then after that, the other last li could be removed. The order of delete shouldn't matter.

Not sure where I went wrong. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: FYI, RESTful operations that modify state should generally use `POST` (or in this case even better `DELETE`) rather than `GET`.

Comment: @kittymeows Couldn't find `btn-delete` class in your HTML, make sure you have applied the class to all required elements

Comment: @Alnitak noted. will change it to POST. first need to find why for example 1st or 2nd or 3rd image cannot be deleted only 5th image can?

Comment: @kittymeows your class in the HTML (`btn-delete-part`) is not consistent with that in the JS code (`btn-delete`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
  $('.btn-delete-part').on('click',function(){

        e.preventDefault();

        var $galleryItem = $(this).closest('.prj-item');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/deletePart/'+$(this).data('id'),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {

                $galleryItem.fadeOut(500, function(){
                    $galleryItem.remove();  
                });

            },
            error: function( error ) {
            console.log( error );

        }
        });
    });
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are adding/removing elements dynamically. In this case you have to use event delegation with [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Quick ref:

> The majority of browser events bubble, or propagate, from the deepest,
>   innermost element (the event target) in the document where they occur
>   all the way up to the body and the document element. In Internet
>   Explorer 8 and lower, a few events such as change and submit do not
>   natively bubble but jQuery patches these to bubble and create
>   consistent cross-browser behavior.
>
> If selector is omitted or is null, the event handler is referred to as
>   direct or directly-bound. The handler is called every time an event
>   occurs on the selected elements, whether it occurs directly on the
>   element or bubbles from a descendant (inner) element.
>
> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as
>   delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on
>   the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that
>   match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up
>   to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to
>   outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that
>   path matching the selector.

Code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn-delete', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var $galleryItem = $(this).closest('.prj-item');

    // AJAX: In success 

    $galleryItem.remove(); 

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/PzB45/

Comment: The OP specifically wants to remove _any_ item, not just the last one.

Comment: @Irvin it is removing last li. I wanted any random li to be removed upon click delete. Shouldn't be deleted from bottom to top...for example, if 5 images, i want to delete 3rd image and it should disappear / be deleted. Then delete 2nd one..etc

Comment: @Alnitak I mixup the problems and the requiriments :-\...now it must be ok

Answer (score 0):

Try a delegated event handler for the last `li` of the `ul` like where the the click handler will be triggered for the `btn-delete` element in the last `li`

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li:last-child .btn-delete', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $galleryItem = $(this).closest('.prj-item');

    $.ajax({
        url: '/deletePart/' + $(this).data('id'),
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (response) {
            $galleryItem.fadeOut(500, function () {
                $galleryItem.remove();
            })
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Get rid of the `li:last-child` - the OP wants _any_ `li` to work, not just the last one.

Comment: @Alnitak in that case, I think `:not(:last-child)` should do?

Comment: @Alnitak but what did the OP meant by `Only the last li could be removed, then after that, the other last li could be removed`

Comment: I believe he meant that once the last item was removed, then he was able to remove what was now the current "last item"

Comment: @ArunPJohny - thanks and i will try your method and hope it works.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I tried the method without last-child but it doesn't work either. the click doesn't do anything. mm.

Comment: @kittymeows the class name seems to be wrong.... try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2jvGC/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny you are correct about class name, but still it only deletes the last child :(. thanks alot for your help. Might be something related to ajax process, because it gives out 500 internal error and it is getting the address url instead of /deletepart

Comment: @kittymeows so if what are you looking for... something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2jvGC/3/

Comment: @kittymeows another way to look at the same is http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2jvGC/4/

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks again for your help, your jsfiddle works, but not on my side. like i mentioned, it keeps giving out 500 internal error and when i clicked on delete icon, on console, it showed that it gets the address url (on browser bar) which is not correct for the first li or any random li (not last).

Comment: @ArunPJohny updated - tried your method but i cannot even click on the remaining li after clicking on all li from bottom to top..:(

Comment: @ArunPJohny - sorry tested your jsfiddle again and found that the remaining 'd' stayed though i clicked on the remaining last 'd' again and again but it wont go away.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$('.btn-delete').click();
```

without the each..

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @irvin - I already tried, but it wouldn't show that first or second images disappear (remove) till trying last image and it disappeared.

Comment: he is trying to bind a click event to every image.. but it doesn't happen like that... the click fires only for the last image because it is the only one to have a click event bind to it..

Comment: @kms no, the `.each` is indeed redundant here, but it's not harmful.

Comment: do the images exist when you load the javascript? Are they dynamic or do they exist on page load.. if they don't exist on page load and you call them with ajax or some other way try using the .on function of jquery..

Comment: @kms, yes they exist and yes they are dynamic. they appears on page load. have tried .on function before i change it to each and click to see if it worked.

Comment: first of all you don't have a class with "btn-delete" and if you do make the link with "x" with that class I think this:

var $galleryItem = $(this).closest('.prj-item');

won't work.. try another way for this.. maybe with parent()

Comment: guys I'm only trying to help and make her think, please stop with the extra comments.. @kittymeows one more thing I can think of.. I know it is stupid but did you put your javascript in a $(document).ready(); if one is working and the rest are not there are 3 reasons I think of: 1. the $(document).ready is missing and some how only the last li is bind a click event (I know its stupid but please check); 2. make sure you are using the right css class selector; 3.maybe this row var $galleryItem = $(this).closest('.prj-item'); is not working as you expect, try getting the parent div in another way

Comment: @kms - all of them are checked. The css selector is correct. I tested $galleryItem = $(this).closest('.prj-item'), it worked for last li to disappear upon click. hmm.

Comment: hmmm.. this is a nasty one.. for the sake of experiment try removing the whole <a> tag for the "X" button in all the li and instead put a span tag with a stupid class like "abc" and text "delete" (maybe the link with your href="javascript:void(0);" is somehow messing things up) then wright the abc class selector for the click. Another thing I can think of is to check your generated HTML. After the page loads in the browser, forget about the javascript, open the page source and make sure the html looks as you expect it to be and that the css selector you pass to the click event exists in html.